# Taking up space after display none

Tags: html, css, nav

When I apply `display: none;` for `#nav-icon` element, it still takes up space. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
  <a href="" id="nav-icon"> <img src="navigation.png" alt="nav-menu"</a>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#"> LINK </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> LINK </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> LINK </a> </li>
    <li class="navimage"> <a href="twitter.com"> <img src="twitter-icon.png" alt="twitter-icon" /> </a> </li>
    <li class="navimage"> <a href="facebook.com"> <img src="facebook-icon.png" alt="facebook-icon" /> </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    max-width:95%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#nav li {
    display:inline;
}

#nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    margin:15px 0;
}

#nav-icon img {
    display:none;
}

.navimage {
    float:right;
    margin-top:-5px;
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: Are you sure the extra space is not just padding around your `#nav a`?

Comment: remove display:inline-block and it works http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/2s54q/1/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have the `img` inside `#nav-icon` hidden. You don't have the actual `<a>` wrap hidden though. Since it's set to `inline-block`, it can display when there is nothing inside it. Change the `display:none` to be on the actual `#nav-icon` instead of `#nav-icon img`, and you'll be good.

You might run into issues of conflicting `display` rules though, because you are applying rules with different selectors on the same element. `#nav a` and `#nav-icon` are the same thing, but one might overrule the other. To make sure you have it selected correctly, the second should include all previous selectors, which would be `#nav a#nav-icon`.

Change:

```
#nav-icon img {
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C4YPR/

To:

```
#nav a#nav-icon {
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C4YPR/1/

Comment: That really works for this problem! Thanks for explaining as well! :)